# Recording Video While Another Video Is Playing React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't figure out how to record a video (video and audio) while the user is also listening and watching another video. Currently the video is simply playing (video and audio) on the screen while the recording is happening. **However, the recording is picking up the audio playing from the video**

**I would like to record a video while listening and watching another video but not pick up the audio of this video**

I'm not sure where to start, any help would be appreciated!